# ASCII art generator

Tags: software-rec, utilities, ascii

I'm looking for an ASCII art generator (text is preferred, but images will do too) in the [`sl`](http://aasen.in/blog/sl/) style, but with text instead of trains. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you considered [`figlet`](http://www.figlet.org)? It writes "large letters" in ASCII art.

Comment: A browser based implementation of figlet http://ascii.gallery/figlet. One thing I like about this is you can embed the result in other websites.

Answer (score 3):

- GNU banner
- figlet
- toilet ([tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-large-colorful-text-banner-on-screen/))

As usual, you can read their man pages with the commands `man banner`, etc.

You might find these scripts useful: [reverse the output horizontally](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Reverse-chars-of-lines), [pad the output](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#fn-8)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this generator [Textart Generator](http://meapage.com/txtart/)

Comment: A webpage isn't exactly "in the `sl` style"