# How do I print 'block' letters in the terminal?

Tags: shell, terminal, special-characters

How do I echo/print block lettering in the terminal like:

[image] ?

`figlet` and `toilet` don't help. Neither do [U+25A0](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25a0/index.htm) or [U+2588](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2588/index.htm) unicode characters.

**This is not a duplicate.** As I said, `figlet`, `banner` and `toilet` have no styles for what I want, as depicted in the image.

Comment: banner, cowsay, and figlet (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIGlet) are all ascii terminal utilities of the golden ages, that is, no unicode.  you could probably add some characters by contemplating their source code.  Eric Olson added OpenType to figlet you could follow his footsteps and add unicode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASCII art generator](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69271/ascii-art-generator).  Also [Colorful ssh banner](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76184/colorful-ssh-banner/76186#76186).  Good questions should reflect some initial investigation.

Comment: @ThomasDickey As I said, `figlet`, `toilet` and `banner` do *not* work, as they don't have the styles/modes for what I want.

Comment: I do not see the problem with `echo "█■"` (provided console font defines the shape and LANG is set to `smthing.utf8`. The latarcyrheb-sun16 does since Fedora20 at least.  )

Comment: Or maybe using terminal escape sequences, like `\033[41m` for red etc. to make the "dots"; foreground colours 40-47, background 30-37... I'm not sure about the 5x7 rendering (other than manually).

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want to handcraft one particular "picture" like this, or are you looking for a utility that can convert any string into such a "picture"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is part of the output of [the `linuxlogo` command](http://www.deater.net/weave/vmwprod/linux_logo/), specifically part of the output of

```
linuxlogo -L gnu_linux
```

which in full looks like [this screenshot from the Debian version](https://screenshots.debian.net/package/linuxlogo):

[image: Screenshots of the linuxlogo command]

The logos are constructed from templates that accompany the command.  [This is the one for the `gnu_linux` logo](https://github.com/deater/linux_logo/blob/master/logos/distributions/gnu-linux.logo).  There are 30 logos in the original package.  Debian adds [a `debian_banner_2` logo](https://sources.debian.org/src/linuxlogo/5.11-9/debian/debian-banner-2.logo/).

From reading these logo files, right there in the source trees, one can see how the several different forms of lettering in the various logos are constructed with ECMA-48 and ISO 8613-6 control sequences, and one can derive further logos of one's own.

Answer (score 5):

You can always use `banner` and convert the `#` to `█` or to a space in reverse video.

On Debian-based systems, you'll find the SysV style `banner` in the `sysvbanner` package and the BSD-style one (called `printerbanner` there) in the `bsdmainutils` package. Or use `figlet -f banner`:

```
$ figlet -f banner test | sed $'s/#/█/g'

█████ ██████  ████  █████
  █   █      █        █
  █   █████   ████    █
  █   █           █   █
  █   █      █    █   █
  █   ██████  ████    █
```

```
$ printerbanner -w 40 test | sed 's/#/█/g'
                         █
             █████████████████
          ████████████████████
          ████████████████████
          ██             █
          ██
            █
               █████
            ███████████
           ██████████████
          ██     █     ██
          █      █       █
          █      █       █
          █      █      ██
           █     ████████
            ██   ██████
                 ███
          ████      ██
          ████    ██████
          ██     ████████
          █     ████     █
          █     ████     █
          █     ████    ██
          █    ████    ██
           ████████   ████
            █████
                         █
             █████████████████
          ████████████████████
          ████████████████████
          ██             █
          ██
            █
```

```
$ banner test | sed 's/#/█/g'

  █████  ██████   ████    █████
    █    █       █          █
    █    █████    ████      █
    █    █            █     █
    █    █       █    █     █
    █    ██████   ████      █
```

For the inverse video space:

```
banner text | sed $'s/#/\e[7m \e[m/g'
```

(`$'...'` is a form of quote available in most modern shells like `zsh`, `ksh93`, `bash`, `mksh` or FreeBSD `sh`. If your shell lacks support for it use `"$(printf 's/#/\33[7m \33[m/g')"` instead).